# Group Theory - subgroups, coprimes

Tags: group-theory

I have the following question:

Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be finite groups and let $K$ be a subgroup of $G_1 \times G_2$.

Set $H_1 = \{ g \in G_1 : (g,e) \in K \}$ and $H_2 = \{ g \in G_2 : (e,g) \in K \}$. Show that:

i) $H_1$ is a subgroup of $G_1$

ii) $H_2$ is a subgroup of $G_2$

iii) $H_1 \times H_2$ is a subgroup of $K$

iv) Suppose that $|G_1|$ and $|G_2|$ are coprime. Show that $K = H_1 \times H_2$.

v) Show that this result need not follow if $|G_1|$ and $|G_2|$ are not coprime.

I think I've done parts (i) and (ii) using the subgroup tests, but this didn't seem to work for part (iii). I've tried using Bezout's Lemma for part (iv) but got nowhere, and I'm pretty sure a counterexample is sufficient to answer part (v) but I can't think of one. Any help with the last three parts would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

$$\begin{align*}&(iii) \;\;(h_1,h_2)\in H_1\times H_2\;,\;\;(h_1,h2)=(h_1,e)\cdot(e,h_2)\\{}\\
&(iv)\;\; \text{show that any $\;k\in K\;$ has a unique expression}\;\;k=(k_1,e)\cdot(e,k_2)\;,\;\;k_i\in H_i\\{}\\
&(v)\;\;K=\langle\,(1,1)\,\rangle\le\Bbb Z_2\oplus\Bbb Z_2\end{align*}$$